# Authenticating Gcloud Kubernetes with just a Service Account kubectl token?

Tags: kubernetes, command-line-interface, gcloud

Following: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#option-2-use-the-token-option

I want to be able to connect to project / cluster context to our GKE clusters.

Normally, one would use gcloud, and login with a browser, or with a password json file.

Is it possible to authenticate with just a service account token that you can feed into kubectl (without using gcloud)?

I cannot get the above documentation working, doesn't seem to connect me to gcloud as I get:

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Never able to connect outside of a local context.

I'm wondering if this is even possible, to connect to GKE clusters using nothing but a service account token?

Comment: As an update, haven't found a solution for this, using gcloud docker, can install `gcloud` and then login with that, before directing kubectl to your region etc..

Comment: This error usually means that your kubectl can't talk to api server, so either server is not where kubectl is expecting it or not running properly. Did you try to [fetch kubectl](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials) config for your cluster which will be stored in $HOME/.kubectl/config by running: $gcloud container clusters get-credentials NAME